# Defining long array dynamic length

Tags: java, sequence

I'm trying to create a program that calculates a number sequence in an iterative way. I'm having difficulties with defining an dynamical length array for my long. When using the below I get "array dimension missing". Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks

```
long seq[] = new long[];
```

Full code:

```
public long calculate(long n) {
        // If n is one of known values return that value
        if(n<=1){
            return 0;
        }
        if(n==2){
            return 1;
        }
        if (n==3){
            return 2;
        }

        // initate array to calculate
        long seq[] = new long[];
        int x = 0;
        seq[0] = 0;
        seq[1] = 0;
        seq[2] = 1;
        seq[3] = 2;

        // for loop until reached requested number
        for (int i = 4; i<=n; i++){
            seq[i] = seq[i-1]+seq[i-3];
        }
        for (int i =0; i<n; i++){
            x++;
        }
        return seq[x];
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you are missing the array dimensions. Perhaps you want to use an `ArrayList<Long>` instead?

Comment: You must provide the length of the array at initialization time. It seems that the size is `n` in your case so you might use  `long seq[] = new long[n];`

Comment: Or you can use `LinkedList`

Comment: There is no dynamic length Array in java like in php or any other loosely typed language, if you want to perform an operation like dynamic length array use LinkedList or ArrayList instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can not code

```html
long seq[] = new long[];
```

like this! There must be an initial Capacity.

Refer to ArrayList source:

```html
/**
     * The array buffer into which the elements of the ArrayList are stored.
     * The capacity of the ArrayList is the length of this array buffer. Any
     * empty ArrayList with elementData == DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA
     * will be expanded to DEFAULT_CAPACITY when the first element is added.
     */
    transient Object[] elementData; // non-private to simplify nested class access
    
    /**
     * Constructs an empty list with the specified initial capacity.
     *
     * @param  initialCapacity  the initial capacity of the list
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the specified initial capacity
     *         is negative
     */
    public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
        if (initialCapacity > 0) {
            this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
        } else if (initialCapacity == 0) {
            this.elementData = EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: "+
                                               initialCapacity);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructs an empty list with an initial capacity of ten.
     */
    public ArrayList() {
        this.elementData = DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
    }
```

If you want dynamically insert:

```html
/**
     * Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this
     * list. Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and
     * any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).
     *
     * @param index index at which the specified element is to be inserted
     * @param element element to be inserted
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public void add(int index, E element) {
        rangeCheckForAdd(index);

        ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
        System.arraycopy(elementData, index, elementData, index + 1,
                         size - index);
        elementData[index] = element;
        size++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dimension is missed because, when you write `[n]` it's one dimension, and when you write `[n,m]` it's two dimensional, and it goes forward like that...

When you just pass empty `[]`. it doesn't know anything about the way you gonna fill your array, so either you need to fill it in place like this: `long[] powers = {..., 2863245995L, 11453115051L, ...};`
`long[] powers = {..., 2863245995L, 11453115051L, ...};`

Or set the dimensions, which also meaning, that you need to set the size. since, you need to use a number or comma separated list of numbers which each represent, size of each dimension. like: `long[] heights = new long[4];`

if you want to force it to be array, and yet dynamically change the size... C# `List` do it like this, which i PERSONALLY think, JAVA `ArrayList` should be same:

```
Initialize:
  create a array of default minimum size which is power of 2, 
  Set a used element count with name such as Count/Length to the number of element that are initially loaded otherwise 0

Adding element: 
  if there is more space, add to free slot, 
  if not, create new array and double the size
    then copy all item to the new array.
  Add to the Count/Length of array
```

Otherwise a `LinkedList` will do the job, which you already should know how it works...